# acro: move translation to the next line for selected acronyms only

Tags: acro

Adopting one example from the `acro` package's manual (p. 38, version 2.10c),

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[version=2]{acro}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\DeclareAcronym{Rv}{short=Rv,long=Fluss,foreign=\textit{river},foreign-lang=english}
\DeclareAcronym{Drs}{short=Drs,long=Donaudampfschiff,foreign=\textit{Donau river steamer},foreign-lang=english}

\begin{document}

\acuseall

\newlist{acronyms}{description}{1}
\newcommand*\addcolon[1]{#1:}
\setlist[acronyms]{
    labelwidth=3em,
    leftmargin=3.5em,
    noitemsep,
    itemindent=0pt,
    font=\addcolon}
\DeclareAcroListStyle{mystyle}{list}{list=acronyms}
\acsetup{list-style=mystyle}
\twocolumn
\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

I would like to move the translation of only the first acronym to the next line, as I think this will increase both readability and visual appearance. Is it possible to prepend a `\linebreak` to user-selected acronyms? Please note that I'm required to use `acro` in compatibility mode, thus the `version=2` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[version=2]{acro}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\DeclareAcronym{Rv}{short=Rv,long=Fluss,foreign=\textit{river},foreign-lang=english}
\DeclareAcronym{Drs}{short=Drs,long=Donaudampfschiff,list=Donaudampfschiff\newline,foreign=\textit{Donau river steamer},foreign-lang=english}

\begin{document}

\acuseall

\newlist{acronyms}{description}{1}
\newcommand*\addcolon[1]{#1:}
\setlist[acronyms]{
    labelwidth=3em,
    leftmargin=3.5em,
    noitemsep,
    itemindent=0pt,
    font=\addcolon}
\DeclareAcroListStyle{mystyle}{list}{list=acronyms}
\acsetup{list-style=mystyle}
\twocolumn
\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

Produces:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In case you should want to use version 3 here is how you then could define a boolean property for acronyms which you could test in a list template and depending on its value insert a linebreak or not. Such a property is defined with

```
\DeclareAcroProperty?{boolean-property}
```

and checked in a template with

```
\acroifbooleanTF{boolean-property}{true}{false}
```

The following example calls it `foreign-newline` and shows a template similar to the predefined `description` template (I left the `extra` and `pages` fields away but they could be added, of course):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\DeclareAcroProperty?{foreign-newline}

\NewAcroTemplate[list]{custom}{
  \acroheading
  \acropreamble
  \begin{description}[
    labelwidth = 3em ,
    leftmargin = 3.5em ,
    noitemsep ,
    itemindent = 0pt]
    \acronymsmapF{%
      \item[\acrowrite{short}\acroifT{alt}{/}\acrowrite{alt}:]%
        \acrowrite{list}%
        \acroifT{foreign}{%
          \acroifbooleanTF{foreign-newline}{\newline}{ }%
          (\textit{\acrowrite{foreign}})
        }%
    }
    { \item \AcroRerun }%
  \end{description}%
}

\acsetup{
  list/template = custom
}

\DeclareAcronym{Rv}{
  short = Rv ,
  long = Fluss ,
  foreign = river ,
  foreign-babel = english
}
\DeclareAcronym{Drs}{
  short = Drs ,
  long = Donaudampfschiff ,
  foreign = Donau river steamer ,
  foreign-babel = english ,
  foreign-newline = true
}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn

\acuseall

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

[image]